# Google Directions API: Get the current step JSON-Object to current position on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am using the Directions API from Google. Now I would like to determine the current step to the current location of a user.

Here is an example from the google website:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "geocoded_waypoints" : [
     {
        "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        "place_id" : "ChIJ7cv00DwsDogRAMDACa2m4K8",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        "place_id" : "ChIJ69Pk6jdlyIcRDqM1KDY3Fpg",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        "place_id" : "ChIJgdL4flSKrYcRnTpP0XQSojM",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        "place_id" : "ChIJE9on3F3HwoAR9AhGJW_fL-I",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     }
  ],
  "routes": [ {
    "summary": "I-40 W",
    "legs": [ {
      "steps": [ {
        "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
        "start_location": {
          "lat": 41.8507300,
          "lng": -87.6512600
        },
        "end_location": {
          "lat": 41.8525800,
          "lng": -87.6514100
        },
        "polyline": {
          "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
        },
        "duration": {
          "value": 19,
          "text": "1 min"
        },
        "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS
        Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
        "distance": {
          "value": 207,
          "text": "0.1 mi"
        }
      },
      ...
      ... additional steps of this leg
    ...
    ... additional legs of this route
      "duration": {
        "value": 74384,
        "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2137146,
        "text": "1,328 mi"
      },
      "start_location": {
        "lat": 35.4675602,
        "lng": -97.5164276
      },
      "end_location": {
        "lat": 34.0522342,
        "lng": -118.2436849
      },
      "start_address": "Oklahoma City, OK, USA",
      "end_address": "Los Angeles, CA, USA"
    } ],
    "copyrights": "Map data ©2010 Google, Sanborn",
    "overview_polyline": {
      "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOnzh@vlbBtc~@tsE`vnApw{A`dw@~w\\|tNtqf@l{Yd_Fblh@rxo@b}@xxSfytA
      blk@xxaBeJxlcBb~t@zbh@jc|Bx}C`rv@rw|@rlhA~dVzeo@vrSnc}Axf]fjz@xfFbw~@dz{A~d{A|zOxbrBbdUvpo@`
      cFp~xBc`Hk@nurDznmFfwMbwz@bbl@lq~@loPpxq@bw_@v|{CbtY~jGqeMb{iF|n\\~mbDzeVh_Wr|Efc\\x`Ij{kE}mAb
      ~uF{cNd}xBjp]fulBiwJpgg@|kHntyArpb@bijCk_Kv~eGyqTj_|@`uV`k|DcsNdwxAott@r}q@_gc@nu`CnvHx`k@dse
      @j|p@zpiAp|gEicy@`omFvaErfo@igQxnlApqGze~AsyRzrjAb__@ftyB}pIlo_BflmA~yQftNboWzoAlzp@mz`@|}_
      @fda@jakEitAn{fB_a]lexClshBtmqAdmY_hLxiZd~XtaBndgC"
    },
    "warnings": [ ],
    "waypoint_order": [ 0, 1 ],
    "bounds": {
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 34.0523600,
        "lng": -118.2435600
      },
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 41.8781100,
        "lng": -87.6297900
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

I thought I could use the start_location field and determine the distance between the current location and the start_location fields but I guess that is wrong.
Has anybody a working solution for this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decode `"points"` tag from `"polyline"` section (from documentation:

> polyline contains a single points object that holds an encoded
>   polyline representation of the step. This polyline is an approximate
>   (smoothed) path of the step.

more information about polyline encoding in Google Maps you can find e.g. [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm)) of each [step](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Steps) and leg from `"legs"` array:

```
"legs": [ {
  "steps": [ {
    ...
    "polyline": {
      "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"         <--- need to decode this string
    },
    ...
  } ]
}]
```

for example via [`PolyUtil.decode()`](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#decode-java.lang.String-) of [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility) and you got a sequence of LatLngs for steps. 
Than you need to create loop via all steps and find step that contains point with current location coordinates via [`PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath()`](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-) call. Something like that:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStringBuilder.toString());
JSONArray legsArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("legs");

// for each leg
for (int i = 0; i < legsArr.length(); i++) {
    // get array of steps
    JSONArray stepsArr = legsArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("steps");
    // for each step
    for (int j = 0; j < stepsArr.length(); j++) {
        // get step
        JSONObject step = stepsArr.getJSONObject(j);
        JSONObject polyline = step.getJSONObject("polyline");
        String encodedPoints = polyline.getString("points");
        // decode encoded path to list of points LatLng
        List<LatLng> decodedPoints = PolyUtil.decode(encodedPoints);
        if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(currentLocation, decodedPoints, true, 100)) {
            // your currentLocation is on the step of route
            // constant 100 - is tolerance in meters
        }
    }
 }
```

If you need to determine exactly segment for `currentLocation`, not entire `step` you need to add loop via all segments in step:

```
...
// decode encoded path to list of points LatLng
List<LatLng> decodedPoints = PolyUtil.decode(encodedPoints);
List<LatLng> segment = new ArrayList(2);
for (int k = 0; k < decodedPoints.size() - 1; k++) {
     segment.clear();
     segment.add(decodedPoints.get(k));
     segment.add(decodedPoints.get(k+1));
     if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(currentLocation, segment, true, 100)) {
           // your currentLocation is on the segment of step
     }
}
```

NB! It's just approach description, not fully functional code.